# How to set float column value with php activerecord?

Tags: php, floating-point, phpactiverecord

I have a table column

```
price FLOAT(10, 2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
```

And Model:

```
class Mytable extends \ActiveRecord\Model{
    static $table_name = 'my_table';
}
```

In php i use

```
$price = 23.54;

$obj = new Mytable();
$obj->price = $price;

$obj->save();

var_dump($price); // 23.54
var_dump($obj->price); // 23
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: Problem solved, i needed to add `static $validates_numericality_of = array(
  array('price', 'greater_than' => 0.00)
 );`.

Comment: That's seems weird? Adding a greather then to make that work: probably some sort of casting issue?

Comment: This trouble was because structure of database was cached and in cache type of field is int) need to delete cache

Comment: Ah, check! maybe add that as an answer for future readers ;D